# Triggering Jenkins Multibranch pipeline when there is a pull request created in GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins Multibranch pipeline. I've configured the APIs(github-webhook and ghprbhook) in GitHub. I want to trigger the Multibranch Pipeline whenever there is a Pull Request on GitHub (without using periodical option).
For example, if i create  pull request on GitHub, then the Jenkins Multibranch pipeline should start scanning and build the Jenkinsfile automatically.
What do i need to do to achieve this?
I would love to try if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the webhook section, you can choose `Let me select individual events` option. Under that you can have `push` selected by default and also can select `Pull Request` which helps you to do wnat you are looking for `Pull request opened, closed, reopened, edited, assigned, unassigned, review requested, review request removed, labeled, unlabeled, or synchronized.`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have selected 'Send everything' under webhook section and it worked for me.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I have selected "Send me everything" under GitHub Webhooks section.
Then I was able to trigger builds automatically whenever a PR is raised on GitHub.

As @RSharma mentioned, I have selected only "Push and Pull Request" under "Let me select individual events" section.

PS: The GitHub branches are automatically detected in Jenkins.